# Bash not doing word expansion after command substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, bash-scripting

[From GNU's Bash Manual Sections 3.5.7: Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#index-word-splitting:%7E:text=The%20shell%20scans%20the%20results%20of,within%20double%20quotes%20for%20word%20splitting.):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting

This implies(?) that `ARRAY=$(echo "a b c")` would result in `ARRAY` being assigned an array composed of three words, namely: `a`, `b` and `c`.

Nonetheless, it results in `ARRAY` being assigned a single word: `"a b c"`. In order to truly trigger word splitting, one needs to enclose the right-hand side expression of the assignment statement in parenthesis: `ARRAY=($(echo "a b c"))`.

These parenthesis, although apparently useless, direct bash into different behaviors. Is the manual wrong? What did I not understand?

Comment: The righthand side of a variable assignment does not undergo word splitting _or_ 'globbing' (filename expansion), as if it was quoted; see [3.7.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html). For array syntax see [6.7](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is fun.

[From GNU's Bash Manual Section 3.4: Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html):

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> name=[value]
>
> All values undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal (detailed below).[…] **Word splitting is not performed**, with the exception of "$@" as explained below. Filename expansion is not performed.

I note that if word-splitting *had* been performed, you still would not have ended up with an array. You would have ended up with three words:

`ARRAY=a` `b` `c`

So you would have assigned `a` to `ARRAY`, and then the shell would have tried to interpret `b` as a command to execute, and `c` as the first argument to pass to it.

Regarding your later example…

`ARRAY=($(echo "a b c"))`

…the parentheses are required to specify that this is an array literal, not a series of separate words to be interpreted separately. You can't use quotes for that, because that would make it a string `"a b c"` instead of an array `(a b c)`.

This is covered in [section 6.7: Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays).

> Arrays are assigned to using compound assignments of the form
>
> name=(value1 value2 … )

Comment: And surrounding the expression with parenthesis makes it not be an assignment statement until after it gets expanded?

Comment: @JonathanGinsburg Oops, I see now that I'd accidentally published an earlier draft of my Answer, not the fuller version I was working on. I've fixed that, and I think it addresses your followup question.

Comment: It absolutely does. However, regarding your sentence “ You can't use quotes for that, because that would make it a string "a b c" instead of an array (a b c)”, it does work. Or were you referring to something else?